# I want to clear Reports->Marketing->Products in Carts,Abandoned Carts from admin panel in magento-2.1.How to achieve it?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, shopping-cart, abandoned-cart

I have deleted all customers, orders from admin panel.

But I also want to delete **"Reports >> Marketing >> Products in Carts, Abandoned Carts"** from admin panel in **"Magento 2.1"**.

How can I do that?

Please guide me!!!

Comment: anyone help me.

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete it from admin panel, You need to remove all data from quote table in database.

So go to your database and Run below SQL query in your database SQL query section.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: this is not working .

Comment: it show error "#1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`magentodb`.`quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `magentodb`.`quote` (`entity_id`))".

Comment: have you add this "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" before query?

Comment: "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" in quote table?

Comment: this is SQL query, you can set FOREIGN_KEY CONSTRAINT disable using this query.  So run this query in sql query section.

Comment: check this screenshot  for more information: https://prnt.sc/kfpz1v

Comment: @LovelySetia have you checked that ?

Comment: Yes, I will check and showing this error:MySQL said: Documentation

#1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`magento_Db`.`quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `magento_Db`.`quote` (`entity_id`))

Comment: @LovelySetia try my updated ans

Comment: First I will execute these "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;",it show run successfully.But after that  when i run TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;it again show same error.

Comment: try to TRUNCATE other tables if other tables will remove then after try to remove quote table

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
It give errors.

Comment: Which table have no records,this can be truncate.Other is not.

Comment: have you tried to run set forign key check and truncate query together ?

Comment: No,firstly i run SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;"and after that TRUNCATE TABLE quote.

Comment: please try both query on same time.

Comment: Pls give me any screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81374/discussion-between-aasim-goriya-and-lovely-setia).

Comment: Please check this : prnt.sc/kggu4l

Comment: have you tried this ? if its working then please accept my ans as a solution

Comment: Yes,I will try and it is working.

Comment: where is the option for accept answer?

Comment: done...........

Comment: Please tell me how to delete only whose data,which customer is not exist in magento 2